# Using PHP Switch Statement to send form data to random URL

Tags: php

So i am trying to wrap my head around this logic. this is code that is on a form processing script. What i want to do is send form data to one of these urls randomly. I was reading to use the switch case logic, but when i use the code you see below, it submits the form data to all 3 URLS. Is there a way so that it only sends to one of them?

```
function post_to_url($url, $data) {
$fields = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
  $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
}
rtrim($fields, '&');

$post = curl_init();

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);


$result = curl_exec($post);

curl_close($post);
}



return $result;

$x = rand(1,3);

switch ($x) {
    case 1:
        post_to_url("http://examplesite1.com/cgi-bin/maxuseradmin.cgi", $data2);
        break;

    case 2:
        post_to_url("http://examplesite2?fid=6646588e54", $data3);
        break;

    case 3:
        post_to_url("http://examplesite1?fid=2fb44e3888", $data4);
        break;
    }
```

the $data variables are arrays --Thanks for the help

Comment: some notes to add - i know that the post_to_url functions work

Comment: [CSI: PHP](http://csiphp.com/blog/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting to all 3 pages, then setting the value of what it returns to $ar1 $ar2 and $ar3.

Store your options in an array, then call `post_to_url()` once.

```
$urls = array(
    array("http://examplesite1.com/cgi-bin/maxuseradmin.cgi", $data2),
    array("http://examplesite2?fid=6646588e54", $data3),
    array("http://examplesite1?fid=2fb44e3888", $data4)
);

$x = rand(0,2);
post_to_url ($urls[$x][0], $urls[$x][1]);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, updated psot to show full code -- thanks for help

Comment: it looks right too but when i upload script it does not submit.

Comment: nope, if  to remove the randomizer code, i would get success responses

Comment: @DavidMaldonado your return statement is outside of your method.

Comment: Hi Matt - it does work, just had a stupid mistake--thanks for the help it was so much easier than i thought :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14822/discussion-between-david-maldonado-and-matt)

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you are calling the functions before the switch statement even happens. This code should work for you as it calls the functions only inside the switch statement:

```
$x = rand(1,3);

switch ($x) {
    case 1:
        post_to_url("http://examplesite1.com/cgi-bin/maxuseradmin.cgi", $data2);
        break;

    case 2:
        post_to_url("http://examplesite2?fid=6646588e54", $data3);
        break;

    case 3:
        post_to_url("http://examplesite1?fid=2fb44e3888", $data4);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `mt_rand()` - it's a bit faster. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

Comment: i tried this and it did not work - i have updated the code to reflect full code. thanks for help

Comment: You have a 'return $result;' statement outside of your function. Put that inside the function and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the first 3 lines you calling your `post_to_url` function

Change your code to

```
$urls = array(
   "http://examplesite1.com/cgi-bin/maxuseradmin.cgi",
   "http://examplesite2?fid=6646588e54",
   "http://examplesite1?fid=2fb44e3888"
);

# don't know what's in $data* but just to give you an idea
$data = array(
    $data2,
    $data3,
    $data4
);
$x = rand(0,2);
post_to_url($urls[x], $data[x]);
```

Comment: Hi alexander,is there a way to make it post to 2 random urls?

Answer (score 0):

Call to the function post_to_url should be inside the switch case statement.
The reason it posts to all 3 is that you are calling this function 3 times even before going to switch case.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually executing your post_to_url function three times on the first three lines. You would want to do something like:

```
$x = rand(1,3);

switch ($x)
{
case 1:
post_to_url("http://examplesite1.com/cgi-bin/maxuseradmin.cgi", $data2);
break;

case 2:
post_to_url("http://examplesite2?fid=6646588e54", $data3);
break;

case 3:
post_to_url("http://examplesite1?fid=2fb44e3888", $data4);
break;
}
```

Comment: see updated code, this did not work, i had this originally, thanks for help

Comment: Might be because you have your return statement outside of your function declaration.